# Tangent Bundle of the open positive orthant

Tags: manifolds

What is the expression for the tangent bundle of the open positive orthant $\mathbb R_+^n$?
I think I know the answer, but just to be sure.
Thanks

Comment: Well it's diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$ so as a bundle its just the trivial bundle $\Bbb R^n\times M \to M$.  In general if $M \subset \Bbb R^n$ with $M$ open in $\Bbb R^n$, $TM$ is just the pullback of $T \Bbb R^n$ along the inclusion (which is also always trivial as a bundle).

Comment: @PVAL Thanks, that what I have expected. What about the tangent bundle for the close positive orthant?